# Why is this Matlab error inconsistent with actual tests?

Tags: matlab, error-handling, grid, interpolation

When I run interp2 having defined my arrays with MESHGRID it produces no error and when defined with NDGRID an error is produced. However, that makes no sense because the error (shown below) claims that NDGRID format is required. Feel free to try it for yourself, the code is below. What is the reason for this inconsistency? And if there is a way to detect the format, why doesn't interp2 just handle both formats? I am running Matlab 2012b.

### Here is the error (triggered by test 2):

```
Error using griddedInterpolant

Data is in MESHGRID format, NDGRID format is required.
Convert your data as follows:
   X = X'; Y = Y'; V = V'; F = griddedInterpolant(X,Y,V)
```

### Test 1 - no error

```
clear
x = linspace(0,2*pi,10);
y = linspace(0,2*pi,10);
[X1,Y1] = meshgrid(x,y);
x = linspace(0,2*pi,4);
y = linspace(0,2*pi,4);
[X2,Y2] = meshgrid(x,y);
u = sin(X1).*cos(Y1);
a = interp2(X1,Y1,u,X2,Y2)
```

### Test 2 - error is triggered

```
clear
x = linspace(0,2*pi,10);
y = linspace(0,2*pi,10);
[X1,Y1] = ndgrid(x,y);
x = linspace(0,2*pi,4);
y = linspace(0,2*pi,4);
[X2,Y2] = ndgrid(x,y);
u = sin(X1).*cos(Y1);
a = interp2(X1,Y1,u,X2,Y2)
```

Comment: It's not `interp2` that is claiming that the `ndgrid` format is required, but the low level function `griddedInterpolant`. If you read the help for `interp2` you'll see that it requires data in `meshgrid` format (which why transposing all of the inputs works). If the data are in the wrong format, the values likely won't be monotonic and "plaid" (interleaved). This is what `griddedInterpolant` checks for and why it throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `interp2`, while using `griddedInterpolant` internally, expects `meshgrid` format input (shown in the help) which is transposed before the `griddedInterpolant` call. `meshgrid` does not validate the input arrays wheras `griddedInterpolant` apparently does.

Since most toolbox functions, including `interp2` are Matlab functions themselves it is pretty easy to see what is going on by just typing `edit interp2` or stepping inside the function while debugging.

Comment: I should probably read the error more closely next time... that makes perfect sense. When I saw griddedInterpolant for some reason I read it as interp2 (i guess since I was issuing interp2 my brain just expected an error related to interp2)